# Merging multiple user identities in Kinvey

Tags: android, kinvey

I've got a question regarding Kinvey's ability to support multiple user identities. I was studying their SignIn app example for Android and here's what I did:

1. Registered a user using email/password combo.
2. Reinstalled the app to reset the cache.
3. Signed in using a Facebook account (the account was registered with the same email from step 1).
4. Checked the dashboard: there were 2 separate users there.

The question is whether it's possible to merge those users into one record. If so, what's the best way to do that? If not, is there an alternative BaaS that can do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an engineer at Kinvey and can help you out.

We do not currently support merging user accounts automatically, however you can use a pre-save business logic hook on the user collection to accomplish this.  When a request is made, you can search the user collection by email and then manually merge the data, update and save the user.

Comment: That's probably the only way that will work at the moment, you are right. Thank you.

Comment: Hi edthethird , where can I find a direct example of a PreSave hook that achieves this goal? Cheers,